# How to check the image size providing image path in jquery?

Tags: android, jquery, image, cordova, image-size

Hai i have a image path location,i need to attach the image when i attach the image i want to check the image size.Its not greater than 1 Mb.Am searching this http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/PKLQn/1/light/,but its input type is file .am using image path location.How to do this?

image path=`content://media/external/images/media/503`.
 i need to check the image size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

If you are using chrome browser,
right click at '

> < input type="file" id="flUpload" />

' to check the property of file dom

(you can select a file first)

After you open the developer tool,
At right column -> Properties -> HTMLInputElement(first one) -> files -> 0: File -> size

You can get the file size

Comment: @ Shinh Thank you Its mobile App

Comment: i didnt use file as input type...i have just path .By using path of image is it possible to check the size?